# Alt + Digit in Terminal: What kind of feature is it?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

In my Ubuntu 12.04 Terminal one can press `Alt + #` which leads to the repeation of the following character #-times.
Simple question: For what is it good for? Is it some fancy feature one can use for some purpose?

Greetz,
Tik0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "feature" doesn't refer to the terminal, but is related to [**readline arguments**](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Arguments) in **bash**.

**For what is it good for?**

> You can pass numeric arguments to Readline commands. Sometimes the
>   argument acts as a repeat count, other times it is the sign of the
>   argument that is significant. If you pass a negative argument to a
>   command which normally acts in a forward direction, that command will
>   act in a backward direction. For example, to kill text back to the
>   start of the line, you might type 'M-- C-k'.
>
> The general way to pass numeric arguments to a command is to type meta
>   digits before the command. If the first 'digit' typed is a minus sign
>   ('-'), then the sign of the argument will be negative. Once you have
>   typed one meta digit to get the argument started, you can type the
>   remainder of the digits, and then the command. For example, to give
>   the C-d command an argument of 10, you could type 'M-1 0 C-d', which
>   will delete the next ten characters on the input line.

More about:

- [Press alt + numeric in bash and you get (arg [numeric]) what is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562115/2353900)

Answer (score 2):

This is not just for characters; it repeats the next command several times. E.g. if you want to delete the next three words type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: Wow `Alt+D` remove a next word!